# Extending Base Datatables Class For Crud Class

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using the yajra laravel datatables package.

I'm trying to figure out how I can refactor this little bit of controller code to an individual class (UsersDataTable) which I am using method injection to make accessible. This class extends the base DataTable class but I have not added any additional functionality to this class yet. This is what I need assistance undertanding.

```php
    public function index(Request $request, UsersDataTable $table, UserFilters $requestFilter)
    {
        $this->authorize('viewList', User::class);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $query = User::with('employment');
            $requestFilter->apply($query);

            return $table->eloquent($query)
                ->addColumn('action', 'users.partials.action-cell')
                ->filterColumn('name', function ($query, $keyword) {
                    $sql = "CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name)  like ?";
                    $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$keyword}%"]);
                })
                ->filterColumn('id', function ($query, $keyword) {
                    $query->where($query->qualifyColumn('id'), $keyword);
                })
                ->toJson();
        }

        return view('users.index');
    }
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;

class UsersDataTable extends DataTables
{

}
```

```html
<!--begin: Datatable -->
<table id="users_table" data-table="users.index" class="table table-hover"></table>
```

```js
const table = $('[data-table="users.index"]');
// begin first table
table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: window.location.href,
        data(params) {
            params.status = filterData.status;
            params.started_at = filterData.started_at;
        },
        error: function(xhr, error, code) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText.errors));
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(error);
            new Noty({
                type: "error",
                layout: "topRight",
                text: JSON.parse(xhr.responseText.errors)
            }).show();
        }
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "id", title: "User ID" },
        { data: "name", title: "Name" },
        { data: "hometown", title: "Hometown" },
        {
            data: "employment.started_at",
            title: "Date Started",
            searchable: false
        },
        { data: "status", title: "Status", searchable: false },
        {
            data: "action",
            title: "Action",
            orderable: false,
            responsivePriority: -1
        }
    ],
    initComplete(settings) {
        rowCounter.html(`${settings.fnRecordsTotal()} Total`);
    }
});
```

My expected results is that my controller code can me refactored to go inside of the UsersDataTable class.

**UPDATE:**

I am working on what was provided to me below however, I have since decided to separate the view from its API to get the collection of users for the table to use so I won't need to create the table with the package. The problem is none of the code in the dataTable method is being ran. What am I doing wrong?

So currently as an update, I have the following.

```
public function index(UsersDataTable $dataTable, UserFilters $requestFilter)
{
    $this->authorize('viewList', User::class);

    $query = User::query();
    $requestFilter->apply($query);

    return $dataTable->eloquent($query)->toJson();
}



<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Filters\UserFilters;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;

class UsersDataTable extends DataTables
{
    /** @var userFilters */
    private $userFilters;

    /**
     * UserDataTable constructor.
     *
     * @param UserFilters $userFilters
     */
    public function __construct(UserFilters $userFilters)
    {
        $this->userFilters = $userFilters;
    }

    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
     public function dataTable($query)
     {
         return datatables($query)
            ->editColumn('started_at', function (User $user) {
                return $user->currentEmployment->started_at->format('Y-m-d H:s');
        })
             ->editColumn('name', function (User $user) {
                return $user->full_name;
            })
            ->filterColumn('id', function ($query, $keyword) {
                $query->where($query->qualifyColumn('id'), $keyword);
            })
            ->filterColumn('name', function ($query, $keyword) {
                $sql = "CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name)  like ?";
                $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$keyword}%"]);
            })
            ->addColumn('action', 'users.partials.action-cell');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query($builder)
    {
        $query = User::with('employment');

        $this->userFilters->apply($query);

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code behind `UserFilters`?

Comment: Are you rendering your DataTable currently by hand with custom HTML and JavaScript code?

Comment: @Namoshek I updated my post with relevant code. The UserFilters is scopes added to the request to retrieve the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

You will basically need to define a `UserDataTable` like the following:

```
class UsersDataTable extends DataTables
{
    /** @var UserFilters */
    private $userFilters;

    /**
     * UserDataTable constructor.
     *
     * @param UserFilters $userFilters
     */
    public function __construct(UserFilters $userFilters)
    {
        $this->userFilters = $userFilters;
    }

    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query): DataTableAbstract
    {
        return datatables($query)
            ->filterColumn('name', function ($query, $keyword) {
                $sql = "CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name)  like ?";
                $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$keyword}%"]);
            })
            ->filterColumn('id', function ($query, $keyword) {
                $query->where($query->qualifyColumn('id'), $keyword);
            })
            ->addColumn('action', 'users.partials.action-cell');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function query(): Builder
    {
        $query = User::with('employment');

        $this->userFilters->apply($query);

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return HtmlBuilder
     */
    public function html(): HtmlBuilder
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->addAction()
            ->ajax(['type' => 'POST'])
            ->parameters(array_merge(
                $this->getBuilderParameters(),
                [
                    'orderBy' => [[2, 'asc']],
                    'fixedColumns' => [
                        'leftColumns' => 1,
                        'rightColumns' => 1,
                    ],
                ]
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns(): array
    {
        return [
            ['data' => 'id', 'title' => trans('users.table.header.id')],
            ['data' => 'name', 'title' => trans('users.table.header.name')],
            ['data' => 'email', 'title' => trans('users.table.header.email')],
            ['data' => 'created_at', 'title' => trans('users.table.header.created_at')],
        ];
    }
}
```

*Note: the columns and such may need some tweaking, it is just an example. This config replaces basically your JavaScript config of the table.*

You can then use it in your controller like this:

```
public function index(UserDataTable $dataTable)
{
    return $dataTable->render('users.index');
}
```

In your `views/users/index.blade.php`, you just need to render the table and its script:

```
<!-- The table -->
{{ $dataTable->table([], true) }}

@push('scripts')
    {!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
@endpush
```

Comment: That's great stuff. Will, that change any of the existing javascript that I have above?

Comment: It replaces it, if you render the scripts. Thats the main use of this package anyway.

Comment: The filters should only be applied if there's an ajax request though,

Comment: So it should return the json.

Comment: The query only executes when it is an ajax request.

Comment: So then are you suggesting this. ```public function index(Request $request, UserDataTable $table)
    {
        $this->authorize('viewList', User::class);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return $table->render('users.index');
        }

        return view('users.index');
    }```

Comment: No, only render. It will return the table data as json for ajax requests and the view for non-ajax requests.

Comment: The big advantage of using a custom `DataTables` class is that it can do both, render your table and deliver the data for the table. The `html()` and `getColumns()` methods are basically what generates the JavaScript code, while the other two methods of the class generate and transform the data of the table. For a fully working table, you need nothing more than exactly what my answer contains.

Comment: @JeffreyDavidson Not sure why you make it so complicated. You can inject your own `UserFilters` into the DataTable instance by passing them as second argument to the `app()->make($class)` method: `app()->make(UsersDataTable::class, ['userFilters' => $userFilters])`. Use this instead of constructor/function dependency injection. If you need a more complex example how to split _rendering_ of and _providing data_ to the table into two controller methods, let me know. It can sometimes be necessary when rendering multiple tables on the same page.

Comment: why isn’t that datatables method being hit though?

Comment: Most likely an issue with your tables JavaScript code. Use the developer tools in your browser to trace the background requests made by the table.

Comment: It’s a problem on the backend not Frontend. It hits the right endpoint and controller but I’m wondering if it’s the methods I’m calling on the class.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. But as written, your code is unnecessarily complex (and redundant). You can simply keep using the `query()` method on the `UsersDataTable` class. Splitting rendering from providing the data isn't all that easy.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do is ONLY return a json data.  What I am wanting to return is the objects properties with that added cell of actions. What I need to take into account is the fact that when I am sending the ajax request I am also sending possible filters.